# Pygame: .set_clip returns first value in list, instead of requested value

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, rect

I am trying to make walking animations for images returned from a sprite sheet.
I am using `.set_clip` to return a portion of the sprite sheet. Everything looks like it should work
But the `.set_clip` is returning the first Rect value in the list that I provide, rather than the item in the list that I call for.
**My Code**

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

xList = (6, 27,48,69)
yList = (24,24,24,24)
wList = (21,21,21,21)
hList = (32,32,32,32)
ani_pos = list(zip(xList, yList, wList, hList))
sprite_num = 0

class Player:

    def __init__(self): 
        playerSheet = pygame.image.load('MainChar1.png').convert() # load sprite sheet
        playerSheet.set_clip(pygame.Rect(ani_pos[sprite_num]))
        self.player = playerSheet.subsurface(playerSheet.get_clip())
        self.x = 320
        self.y = 240
    def draw(self, DISPLAYSURF):
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.player, (self.x, self.y))
        self.player.set_colorkey(255, 0, 255)# set sprite background invisible

class Background:

    def __init__(self):
        dirtTile = pygame.image.load('DirtBackground.png').convert()
        dirtTile.set_clip(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 863, 1103))
        self.background = dirtTile.subsurface(dirtTile.get_clip())
        self.x = -111
        self.y = -311      
    def draw(self, DISPLAYSURF):
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.background, (self.x, self.y))

pygame.init()
FPS = 30
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

# set up the window
WINDOWWIDTH = 640 # size of windows' width in pixels
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480 # size of windows' height in pixels
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('farm game')
player = Player()
background = Background()
pygame.key.set_repeat(1,0) # (mSec to begin repeat, mSec between repeats)
running = True

while running: # the main game loop

    DISPLAYSURF.fill (255,255,255)
    background.draw(DISPLAYSURF)
    player.draw(DISPLAYSURF)
    pygame.display.flip()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            running = False

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_d:
                background.x -= 4
                sprite_num = 2
```

Comment: you mean that no matter what sprite_num is, ani_pos[sprite_num] returns ani_pos[1]?

Answer (score 2):

> I am using .set_clip to return a portion of the sprite sheet.

No, you don't. You use [`subsurface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.subsurface) to return a portion of the sprite sheet.

---

I don't know what you think what [`set_clip`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.set_clip) does, but it's probably not what it actually does:

> This is a rectangle that represents the only pixels on the Surface that can be modified.

Better explained at the [SDL docs](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsetcliprect.html):

> Sets the clipping rectangle for a surface. When this surface is the destination of a blit, only the area within the clip rectangle will be drawn into.

---

> But the .set_clip is returning the first Rect value in the list that I provide, rather than the item in the list that I call for.

`set_clip` does not return any Rect value of any list at all.

When you call `pygame.Rect(ani_pos[sprite_num])`, you're creating a `Rect` with the values in the list `ani_pos` at index `sprite_num`, and `sprite_num` is `0` when the `__init__` method is called.

You store your `Surface` that you create in the `__init__` method in the `player` field, but you never actually change it. If you want to create some kind of animation, you should change it every `n` frames. You change `sprite_num` to `2`, but that does not do anything since you never use that value again.

Comment: Either Subsurface, or use a **source rect** when you blit.